# Buenas alguien me podria aconsejar como modificar el codigo?

Tags: mips32

Quiero que el programa me deje escribir como maximo 10 lineas o cuando llegue a la marca final XX, i haga el conteo total de palabras, caracteres i lineas introducidas. Tengo este codigo he intentado que lo haga linea por linea pero me esta costando si alguien me podria ayudar. Gracias.

.data
frase: .space 800       # Espacio para almacenar una línea de 80 caracteres
CANVI_LINIA: .byte 0x0a
ESPAI: .asciiz " "
missatge1: .asciiz "\nEntra com a maxim 10 linies de 80 caracters cadascuna\n"
missatge2: .asciiz "Acaba cada frase amb un RETURN i si vols plegar entra la frase 'XX'\n"
missatge3: .asciiz "\nEl numero de linies es: "
missatge4: .asciiz "\nEl numero de paraules es: "
missatge5: .asciiz "\nEl numero de caracters es: "
final: .asciiz "XX"

.text
.globl main

main:
# Imprimir primer mensaje
li $v0, 4
la $a0, missatge1
syscall

```
# Imprimir segundo mensaje
li $v0, 4
la $a0, missatge2
syscall

# Inicializar contadores
li $t4, 0       # Contador de líneas
li $t5, 10      # Límite máximo de líneas
li $t7, 0
li $t8, 0
li $t2, 0
la $t6, final
la $t1, CANVI_LINIA
la $t9, ESPAI
```

linies:

```
    # Leer línea introducida por el usuario
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, frase
    li $a1, 800
    syscall
    
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    
loop:   
    lb $t3, frase ($t2)
    beq $t3, $t6, cont
    beq $t3, $t9, incrementar
    bne $t3, $t9, increment
    beq $t3, $t1, linies
    
    
    j loop
    
    incrementar:
    addi $t7, $t7, 1
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j loop
    
    increment:
    addi $t8, $t8, 1
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j loop
    2
    cont:
    addi $t8, $t8, 2
    addi $t7, $t7, 1
    
    beq $t4, $t5, contador
    
    
    contador:
       # Imprimir número de líneas
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, missatge3
    syscall
    move $a0, $t4
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, missatge4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t7
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, missatge5
    syscall
    move $a0, $t8
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
     # Salir del programa
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```